# "Spaces" or Multiple Desktops for one Monitor on a Multi-Monitor system?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I'm running Windows 7 x64 and three monitors. I wonder if there is a program that allows me to create multiple Workspaces/Desktops and switch between them, but only on the third monitor? (As my main application runs on the two others and the third one is an Utility-Monitor).

Essentially something like OS X Spaces or the Gnome/KDE multiple desktops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard good things about [Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?id=download) which seems to mirror the OS X functionality pretty well.  It's also free for personal use, which is always a nice thing.

Comment: That one works perfectly, supports selections of the monitors to switch.