# Dexpot - Exclude Monitor(s) Settings?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I´m running Windows 7 with a dual monitor setup.

I would like to use the main monitor for multiple desktops, but keep the secondary monitor always the same for my Outlook and IM client.

I've tried VirtuaWin, Dexpot and nSpaces that support dual monitors. But they always activate both monitors. [This article recommends Dexpot](https://superuser.com/questions/338701/spaces-or-multiple-desktops-for-one-monitor-on-a-multi-monitor-system) but I couldn´t find the settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Spaces" or Multiple Desktops for one Monitor on a Multi-Monitor system?](http://superuser.com/questions/338701/spaces-or-multiple-desktops-for-one-monitor-on-a-multi-monitor-system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Dexpot 1.6 Beta](http://dexpot.de/index.php?id=beta16).

See `Settings/Switching Desktops/Multi-Monitor`.

[image: Dexpot Screenshot]

Comment: Thank Sebastian Brands, that exactly what I needed. I didn´t consider trying the beta version before.

Comment: This helped me. I knew to use the beta version but I simply could not find the settings!