# Creating a third virtual monitor, switching view on a second physical monitor (software)

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I currently have two physical monitors. I would like to have a third virtual monitor running in place of the second physical monitor.

The virtual third monitor's display would replace the physical second monitor's display, but I want to be able to switch between the two displays as simply as a hotkey. (I'll settle for a system tray button.) During all this, my primary monitor should not be affected.

I would like to be able to move programs in between the displays, as if viewing Control Panel → Screen Resolution shows an actual third monitor.

I do not want to create a virtual display that I can view only through connecting with a separate device, like TeamViewer. I'd like to be able to just flip one monitor back and forth between the two displays.

The chunk of things here on SU aren't what I'm looking for. A program called ["Desktops"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops) provides a good switching function, but it switches all monitors at once (the entire desktop) and does not allowing moving windows between the virtual desktops.

How can I create such a configuration?

Comment: I don’t know how to do what you want, but I believe that you're asking the question wrong. I think that you want to have three [workspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workspace#Graphical_interfaces)s, or virtual desktops, and you want to be able to switch your second (physical) monitor between the second and third workspaces. Try searching for those terms.

Comment: Thank you, that's actually what I needed. This question solved my issue. https://superuser.com/questions/338701/spaces-or-multiple-desktops-for-one-monitor-on-a-multi-monitor-system?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

G-Man was able to point me in the right direction. This related question got me a similar program that did what I required it to do. ["Spaces" or Multiple Desktops for one Monitor on a Multi-Monitor system?](https://superuser.com/questions/338701/spaces-or-multiple-desktops-for-one-monitor-on-a-multi-monitor-system?rq=1)